# Inserting data from multiple form fields which are the same

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

Sorry if the title is misleading, but I really couldn't think of anything better.

Firstly, I have two tables, banlist and proof. For my problem banlist is more or less irrelevant, but proof is.

```
Table: proof

proofid - primary key
banid - foreign key (links to banlist)
proof - stores the link which acts as the proof
type - stores the type of the proof (image, demo, ...)
```

I also have a form which allows the administrator to provide details regarding a ban and then link any proof. As a ban may have multiple proof, I will be implementing a link which creates a new instance of the two form fields (probably via jQuery). The form can be seen below:

```
<p>Proof (if no proof is available, enter N/A):</p><input type="textfield" name="proof" style="border: solid 1px #<?php echo $pbg?>"/>

<select name="prooftype" style="border: 1px solid #<?php echo $ptbg ?>" />
    <option value="TZAC">TZAC</option>
    <option value="UAC">UAC</option>
    <option value="ESL Wire">ESL Wire</option>
    <option value="GV">GV</option>
    <option value="PB Bans">PB Bans</option>
    <option value="Demo">Demo</option>
    <option value="League">League</option>
    <option value="Image">Image</option>
    <option value="Stream">Stream</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

The problem, or potentially not a problem, is how I am going to insert the multiple instances of the data into the proof table (and eventually update). I just cannot see how if I had 4 of the above I could insert all 4 with their different values into the table.

Would it make sense to set the id of both the textfield and select to be id="proof1"/id="type1", id="proof2"/id="type2", id="proof3"/id="type3" and so forth and to store these in an array, and then loop through the array querying the table with the data entered in the currently selected textfield/select?

Finally, with the administrator being able to edit the bans, I face a similar problem in that say a ban had 4 types of proof, I would need to update the proof in the table for the selected ban.

I currently have this query:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE proof SET proof = '$proof', type = '$type' WHERE banid = $id";
```

However, that will overwrite all the rows with the same banid, whereas I would only want it to update the row specific to that of the proof. Would creating a hidden field alongside each textfield/select box work, by storing the proofid and then modyfying the UPDATE SQL command to be `... WHERE proofid = $_POST['...']`? Again, I would assume I would need some type of array in order to loop through each instance.

---

This image shows part of the form and the colours represent the link between the form fields. From it you can see that I need to take each of the 4 examples of proof and either insert them or update them accordingly.

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/adkfti.png]

Apologies if parts are misclear. You can probably tell that I'm facing a brick wall personally and it's most likely just me needing to get my head around it. Just to add, I may have answered the questions in the post, but I'd like thoughts and ideas for any improvements to using an array.

I appreciate any help or direction you can give,

Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll need a many to many relationship unless you really want full normalization of your data with the prooftype. Your current structure should suffice.

Since you're using PHP on the backend just turn your inputs into an array by appending [] to each one like this:

```
<p>Proof (if no proof is available, enter N/A):</p><input type="textfield" name="proof[]" style="border: solid 1px #<?php echo $pbg?>"/>

<select name="prooftype[]" style="border: 1px solid #<?php echo $ptbg ?>" />
etc...
```

The brackets after the name allow PHP to receive the input as an array and then you can loop it on the PHP side:

```
<?php
// Assuming banid is a hidden field in the form
$banid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['banid']);
$proof = $_POST['proof'];
$prooftype = $_POST['prooftype'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($proof); $i++) {
    $currentProof = mysql_real_escape_string($proof[$i]);
    $currentProofType = mysql_real_escape_string($prooftype[$i]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO proof (banid, proof, prooftype) VALUES ($banid, '$currentProof', '$currentProofType');";
    etc...
}
```

To get around your UPDATE problem, I would just keep it simple and add one more column to your proof table called, proof_number. This would be either 0 through 3 or 1 through 4 to mark which proof the record is for. This avoids you needing to add a proof id in the html form. Then in your UPDATE you can just use the index of the array in your for loop to determine which proof you are updating.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a look into and see where I get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a 3rd table to relate banlist to proof.  Insert relationship entries in this BanProofRelationship table, which contains a banId and ProofId.  This way you can store as many foreign keys to these tables as you wish.  you will end up with a many to many relationship, and when you need to add entries, you'll INSERT them.  When you want to remove entries, you'll DELETE them.

To add an entry, you'd use

`INSERT BanProofRelationship ( banId, proofId ) values (1, 4);`